# sonar code coverage problem with ANT build

Tags: ant, sonarqube

hey all,
i am using    sonar 2.6. my project uses ant build.xml. pls can sm1 tell me how to use sonar with ant build file in order to get the code coverage as well.

P.S. i am using Corbertura plugin for code coverage.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The first result of a google search for "sonar ant" leads me [here](http://www.sonarsource.org/tag/ant/) .
Everything is explained there.

Comment: the wiki documentation can be found here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+ANT